# Making more complex tables using dplyr and tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a dataset that looks like this, though the real example has a lot more columns. There is only one row (at the moment).

```
Results <- structure(list(PCV2_CT_Min = 7.15, PPV2_CT_Min = 11.4, PPV3_CT_Min = 8.6, 
PPV4_CT_Min = 16.3, PPV_CT_Min = 29.58, NI_BOCA_CT_Min = 20.51, 
SW_BOCA_CT_Min = 23.49, PCV2_CT_Count = 695L, PPV2_CT_Count = 695L, 
PPV3_CT_Count = 695L, PPV4_CT_Count = 695L, PPV_CT_Count = 695L, 
NI_BOCA_CT_Count = 695L, SW_BOCA_CT_Count = 695L),
.Names = c("PCV2_CT_Min", "PPV2_CT_Min", "PPV3_CT_Min", "PPV4_CT_Min", "PPV_CT_Min", "NI_BOCA_CT_Min", "SW_BOCA_CT_Min", "PCV2_CT_Count", "PPV2_CT_Count", "PPV3_CT_Count", "PPV4_CT_Count", "PPV_CT_Count", "NI_BOCA_CT_Count", "SW_BOCA_CT_Count"),
row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Each column name is made from a variable name and a function name, so PCV2_CT_Min is the smallest count (CT) for the PCV2 viral test; PCV_CT_Count is the total number of animals tested, and so on.

It is made by running *summarize_all* from *dplyr* on another dataset, of individual viral tests on pigs, using a much longer version of this code :-

```
V <- Pig %>%
     select(ends_with('CT')) %>% 
     summarise_all(funs(Min = min(.,na.rm=TRUE),
     Count = n()))
```

In the real example, there are a lot more functions, and they take different arguments. What I would like to end up with is a dataframe like this :-

```
Parameter PCV_CT PPV2_CT PPV3_CT PPV4_CT PPV_CT NI_BOCA_CT SW_BOCA_CT
Min       7.15   11.4    8.6     16.3    29.58  20.51     23.49
Count     695    695     695     695     695    695       695
```

I had thought there was an easy way to do this, perhaps using something like the *seperate* command from *tidyr*, but I have racked my brains, searched SO, and the wider web, and reviewed the *tidyr* documentation, all to no avail. I think the answer ought to be obvious, but I cannot see it.

I would appreciate any and all help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `gather` all the columns, `separate` the names into the relevant pieces you want, then `spread` the data back into a wide form:

```
library(tidyverse)
Results %>% 
  gather(var, val, everything()) %>% 
  extract(var, into = c("var", "measure"), regex = "(.*)_(Min|Count)") %>% 
  spread(var, val)
# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#   measure NI_BOCA_CT PCV2_CT PPV_CT PPV2_CT PPV3_CT PPV4_CT SW_BOCA_CT
# *   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1   Count     695.00  695.00 695.00   695.0   695.0   695.0     695.00
# 2     Min      20.51    7.15  29.58    11.4     8.6    16.3      23.49
```

---

A more general regex to split on might be `regex = "(.*)_(.*)"`, which could be useful if you have multiple other summarisation functions that were used.

---

I understand that you would have your reasons to have your data in this form, but it's a bit opposite to what you should actually be looking at. Ideally, it makes more sense to have your columns comprise data of all the same type of measures....

Comment: What's the advantage of using `tidyr::extract` over `tidyr::separate`?

Comment: The data are messy, but one area that is not easy in R is producing these sorts of tables, and this, or some variant of it, seems the easiest way to do so. Your answer was very helpful, and I will go off and work on it. Thank you!

Comment: @jdobres, `extract` will let you specify different capturing groups, while `separate` is more like a `strsplit` into new columns. If all variables had the same number of underscores, it would be easier to just use `separate`.

Answer (score 1):

Two different ideas using base R/`reshape2` might be:

**Split and stack:**

```
dfs <- lapply(c("Min", "Count"), function(x) {
        res <- Results[, grepl(x, names(Results))]
        res <- setNames(res, gsub(paste0("_", x), "", names(res)))
        res$measure <- x
        return(res)
      })
do.call(rbind, dfs)

# A tibble: 2 x 8
#  PCV2_CT PPV2_CT PPV3_CT PPV4_CT PPV_CT NI_BOCA_CT SW_BOCA_CT measure
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>   <chr>
#1    7.15    11.4     8.6    16.3  29.58      20.51      23.49     Min
#2  695.00   695.0   695.0   695.0 695.00     695.00     695.00   Count
```

**Melt and dcast:**

```
library(reshape2)
melted <- melt(data.frame(Results))
melted$measure <- gsub(".*_(Min|Count)", "\\1", melted$variable)
melted$variable <- gsub("_(Min|Count)", "", melted$variable)
dcast(melted, measure ~ variable)

#  measure NI_BOCA_CT PCV2_CT PPV_CT PPV2_CT PPV3_CT PPV4_CT SW_BOCA_CT
#1   Count     695.00  695.00 695.00   695.0   695.0   695.0     695.00
#2     Min      20.51    7.15  29.58    11.4     8.6    16.3      23.49
```